# How to display products dynamically in ebay storefront

Tags: ebay-design-templates

I have a store in eBay.

I want to customize it.. I have changed the header with my custom HTML I want to display products in my storefront.

In my shop homepage I found this code  `{eBayStoresItemList DISPLAY="1"}`  I know it stands for gallery view.

My question how can I set items count because when I use this code it displays a bulk of products in a same page. I want to set limit to four items that should be displayed dynamically from the list of items.

Is there any possible way to do it. If so please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

ps: The same question was also posted in the forum and it is also unanswered https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/23769/ebay-stores-item-list-limit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an useful link where you can find the relevant tags and codes for ebay store listings.

Link: https://madetobeunique.com/blog/ebay-store-tags-and-html-codes-for-custom-design/

However, you can set the item limit with the `SIZE` parameter(or whatever you like to call it as)

Use `{eBayStoresItemList DISPLAY="1" SIZE="4"}`  This will automatically sets limits to four items.

The remaining items will be on next pages linked with pagination.

Hope this helped you :)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked well.. I still need to set 4 items per row currently it shows 3 items per row is there any other way?

Comment: I think you can't change the layout because it will affect  `Site Interference Policy` maybe you could list your items in a custom design Refer the link and read the answer for question number 12 https://pages.ebay.com.my/stores/newstore.html